# Concise implementation of DCT, DFT in C#?

Tags: algorithm, c#-3.0, signals, dft, dct

I have been looking at various implementations of [Discrete Cosine Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform) and [Discrete Fourier Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) implemented in C#, yet none is as concise as I would like.

- A bonus point would be, code derived from a larger **open source** project (i.e. *tried and tested*).
- The answer with the *best pointers* will be the *accepted answer*.

**Found** so far

- [DCT Implementation in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43782/DCT-Implementation-in-C-DCT-of-Image)
- [DCT & IDCT](http://www.az3749.narod.ru/dct_cs.htm) (copyrighted, 'untested', slow)
- [Aforge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) (well optimized)

**PS:** In principal I am looking for 1D-implementations, but '*vectorizing*' the input-data is trivial, so classical 2D implementations are just as welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Is it critical that the library be implemented in C#, or would C work for you?

If C is acceptable rather than C# then you can use the [GNU Scientific Library (GSL)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Fast-Fourier-Transforms.html).  There the fast Fourier transform (FFT) is implemented, [which gives you the DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Definition_and_speed).  GSL also provides the [FFT restricted to real data](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Overview-of-real-data-FFTs.html), which I think is exactly the discrete cosine transform you mention.

Comment: Crucial is only cross-platform compatibility through the `mono platform`. You mean rather than P/Invoke's of machine dependent libraries, compile the ANSI C sources to MSIL?

Comment: The truth is I'm a C programmer and I don't know very much about C# or MSIL, so I don't know if something like that is going to work for you.